# Error: Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am getting the error "Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" from my c# code below:

```
 public class Holiday
{

    string startDate, endDate, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, numberOfGuests;
    private double Cost = 100;
    public Holiday(string start, string end, string first, string last, string email, string guestCount)
    {
        startDate = start;
        endDate = end;
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        emailAddress = email;
        numberOfGuests = guestCount;
    }

    public double test
    {
        get { return Cost; }
    }
}
 public class AdventureHoliday : Holiday
{
    public AdventureHoliday(string start, string end, string first, string last, string email, string guestCount)
        : base(start, end, first, last, email, guestCount)
    {
    }
    public double totalcost()
    {
        double adventureAdditional = 0.50;
        double xcost = test + (test * adventureAdditional);
        return xcost;
    }
}

public class CulturalHoliday : Holiday
{

    public CulturalHoliday(string start, string end, string first, string last, string email, string guestCount)
        : base(start, end, first, last, email, guestCount)
    {
    }
    public double totalcost()
    {
        double culturalAdditional = 1.0;
        double xcost = test + (test * culturalAdditional);
        return xcost;
    }
```

I have looked at the various threads for this problem and they all seem to indicate that the problem should be solved by adding:

```
: base(start, end, first, last, email, guestCount)
```

I have added this to the second class and am still getting the error.  I am getting this for both the Adventure Holiday and Cultural Holiday on lines 201 and 125 
    (public class AdventureHoliday : Holiday)

and

```
public class CulturalHoliday : Holiday
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Sorry if I have missed something stupid.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line exactly is giving you the error? Is it a compile-time or runtime error?

Comment: Show the class `Holiday`. You also haven't shown the code where   you call a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Sorry missed Holiday.  Has now been added.

Comment: Added line number info

Comment: @user3174012: there's still no problem with your code. Btw, instead of mentioning the line numbers (that we don't see) you should tell us on which lines exactly you get the compiler(?) error.

Comment: Added exact lines for error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a default `parameterless` constructor manually

```
public Holiday ()
{ 
   ...
}
```

Probably you are trying to create a Holiday instance without passing any parameter like this:

```
var holiday = new Holiday();
```

or:

```
var cultural = new CulturalHoliday();
```

By default all classes inherit a default parameterless constructor from `Object` class.But if you add a constructor that takes some arguments,you need to add parameterless constructor manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else, you shouldn't need a parameterless constructor unless the class is being serialized.

You must provide more information, i.e. the exact line which originates the error, the constructor of the class Holiday (at least the signature), and which classes does class Holiday inherit from.

Comment: if the class is used as a generic parameter that requires `new()` then you will require a parameterless default constructor.